# How to open a PDF file in a specific App using .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have .Net Maui 7 App on Android.

I'm trying to open a PDF file using a specific app. I'm using the following code:

```
await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("https://someurl.com/file.pdf");
```

The problem is that the app I'd like to open is not the list of suggested apps to open the PDF. I have only Drive PDF Viewer and Chrome.

Is there a way to open the file using a specific app?

Comment: What specific app is this? and does the app have the feature of opening PDF files?

Comment: I suggest that you repeat your question with "Android". When you see what lies behind those intents, you can repeat the question once more with "Xamarin". And you will get something closer to MAUI. (Edit: I am talking about running platform specific code, if I was not clear enough. Not with the Launcher... )